# How can I know the threads are working correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java and I try to understand the threads functionalities of the language.

From what I understood, Threads allow to run code "at the same time".

So I created a `MyThread` class in order to test it:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public MyThread (String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void run () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(this.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `Main` class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread myThreadA = new MyThread("A");
        myThreadA.start();

        Thread myThreadB = new MyThread("B");
        myThreadB.start();
    }
}
```

When I use an `i < 10`, the `A` and `B` are *not always* displayed in the same order.

However, when I use an `i < 1000`, I get always the same output, and the `A` and `B` are always in the same order. First the `A`s and then the `B`s.

**How can I make sure the two threads are running simultaneously? 
In a real app, how are the threads dispatched in the different CPUs? Do we have to configure something somewhere in order to get that functionality working?**

Comment: You can't. This underlies the thread management of the CPU. What you could do, is to work with a shared semaphore.

Comment: Try adding a Thread.sleep() in your thread run methods. Also try using a random delay. This way you will probably get a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: That functionality **is** working. The OS is just free to schedule threads the way it wants to, and you thus have no guarantee that A will execute before B, or B before A, or that their execution will be interlaced. Unless of course you explicitly use locks or semaphores or other kinds of concurrency abstraction to order instructions. But if you have two independant threads, then you shouldn't do anything, and just rely on the OS to schedule threads in a reasonable way.

Comment: "How can I make sure the two threads are running simultaneously?" I read that you are not able to do that. The OS will decide for itself which thread to execute.

Comment: You main need to check on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hysb7hXp8B0

Comment: I have a question regarding two threads are running simultaneously.Suppose my computer's processor has multiple cores. So theoretically it can run two threads at the same time right? So thread scheduler assign threads accordingly?

Comment: @KalharaAmarasinghe, only possible if you computer has only one process (yours) running

Comment: @KalharaAmarasinghe even with multiple cores, each core will most probably always multi thread a few threads. So this does not really matter.